# Log4j не создает файл

Tags: java, spring, логирование, log4j

Есть Spring boot приложение. Хочу добавить туда логирование log4j. 
Создал файл конфигурации log4j.properties в resources. 
При запуске приложения файл не создается. Хотя в консоль вроде бы выводится. По крайней мере я вижу следующее при запуске:

```
2018-06-26 18:52:33.525  INFO 4496 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-06-26 18:52:33.530  INFO 4496 --- [           main] com.edsson.expopromoter.api.Application  : Started Application in 7.332 seconds (JVM running for 8.14)
2018-06-26 18:52:33.530  INFO 4496 --- [           main] com.edsson.expopromoter.api.Application  : =================== APPLICATION STARTED ======================
```

Вот мой файл конфигурации:

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO, file
log4j.rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File= log.log

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p    %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]
Есть предположение, что может конф файл не распознается как конфигурационный?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводимые сообщения не соответствуют формату

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p    %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Значит Ваш конфигурационный файл не читается вообще

> Создал файл конфигурации log4j.properties в resources.

А [документация](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) говорит, что он должен лежать в `classpath`

Кроме того, называться он должен А еще он должен называться log4j**2**.properties

Comment: Я добавил папку ресорс в classpath как описано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765998/add-a-properties-file-to-intellijs-classpath. Результат не увидел..

Comment: А еще он должен называться log4j**2**.properties

Comment: Не верю
https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/

Comment: А зря `classic log4j 1.2.x ` Вы тоже используете версию 1.2? Или все таки 2.х? Зачем верить или не верить, если есть документация и ссылку на нее я привел

Comment: В целом, я согласен с аргументом о документации. Фраза "не верю" была в дружеском тоне сказана) Сейчас пробую Ваш вариант

Comment: Я поставил лог4ж2 ничего, увы, не изменилось

Comment: Какая у вас структура проекта и куда вы положили файл? Он должен лежать в папке `src`

Comment: Удобно скайп? Я бы кинул скрин.
project->src->resources

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79392/discussion-between-anton-shchyrov-and-artemk).